# Help with simple query - why isn't an index being used?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT MAX([LastModifiedTime]) FROM Workflow
```

There are approximately 400M rows in the Workflow table. There is an index on the LastModifiedTime column as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Workflow_LastModifiedTime] ON [dbo].[Workflow] 
(
 [LastModifiedTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100)
```

The above query takes 1.5 minutes to execute. Why wouldn't SQL Server use the above index and simply retrieve the last row in the index to get the maximum value?

BTW, the query plan for this query shows an `index scan` being done on the above index.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to do an `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Workflow` or `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Workflow IX_Workflow_LastModifiedTime` and see if that makes any difference??

Comment: @marc_s - It's using the index, but it's scanning it. Why wouldn't it just drop down to the last row? That's going to be the maximum value. Unless it takes 1:30 just to drop down to the last row when there are 400M rows in the index?

Comment: yes, and maybe if you update the statistics, the query optimizer will notice that there are too many rows to just scan - and find some other strategy to get at the result needed....

Comment: Have you tried adding a DESC index?

Comment: @Lieven - Yes I tried a Desc index. But it still wanted to do an index scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysterious are the ways of the query optimizer...

If is possible, I'd recommend you change the query like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [LastModifiedTime]
FROM Workflow 
ORDER BY [LastModifiedTime] DESC;
```

This is semantically identical and the optimizer will no longer consider using the MAX aggregate and scan (which apparently it does right now). It may consider doing a SORT in a worktable, but hopefully the estimated cost of such a plan would be much bigger than the cost of the reverse order seek.

As to why does the optimizer choose what apparently is an obviously bad plan, there are usually many many factors involved and is hard to diagnose just from a SO post. In general, having an ASC index does not always substitute for the lack of a DESC index and your particular column statistics (distribution) may had hit some tipping point inside the query optimizer where it decided to choose the scan+aggregate instead of the reverse scan+top.

Answer (score 1):

I have a table with a similar date-time field (assuming that is your datatype) and 4M rows - 1% of yours, but the same query came back almost as soon as I clicked 'execute'. My index is *almost* the same as yours:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PartViewTrack_SearchDate] ON [dbo].[PartViewTrack] 

(
[SearchDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,     
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The execution plan shows an index scan.

Just for grins - drop the index and see how long it takes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell from the execution plan if it is using the index or not?  If not, when was the table/index last analyzed?  If it's never been analyzed, maybe SQL server still thinks there's only 100 rows in it and it would just be faster to do a table scan.

Comment: The index on this column was just added about two hours ago. They query plan shows an index scan being done on the index.

Comment: @Randy Jut out of curiosity, how long does this query take: `SELECT TOP 1 LastModifiedTime FROM WorkFlow ORDER BY LastModifiedTime DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX([LastModifiedTime]) FROM Workflow with(nolock)
```

Is this any faster?

Comment: it might be marginally faster but the real problem is that it's doing an index scan instead of a seek. Adding with(nolock) doesn't change this.

Answer (score 0):

A black-and-white problem, without (to me) an obvious answer. Here are some pretty dumb ideas, just to clear the air.

- Is it a table? If a view, underlying
  structure might get in the way. (I
  forget, can you build a nonclustered
  index on a materialized view?)
- Is there contention? If other users
  have long-standing locks on the
  table, that might slow it down. 
  Also, extremely frequent updates
  might throw it off.
- The query plan shows an index scan
  being run. Is the index reference
  *this* index? (Are there other indexes? A clustered indexes?
  Probably not an issue, but scrabbling
  for ideas here.)
- Do you use schemas? The index is on
  dbo.Workflow, but the query does not
  specify "dbo". (Like I said,
  scrabbling for ideas here.)

All of those sound pretty lame, but without hands-on access these kinds of problems can be pretty tough to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a longshot:  I have found that Oracle sometimes requires a field to not allow nulls before it will use an index on it.  Are there any similar restrictions in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Analyse your index first using the command

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (table_name, index_name)
```

Check if your index is covering the whole table. If not, try updating your statistics using

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_name
```